# Is it possible to add annotation to generated class from avro schema?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, apache-beam, avro

I use gradle plugin for generating classes from avro schema(com.github.davidmc24.gradle.plugin.avro), is it possible to add any annotation for ex, @DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class) to class level when class is generating?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is indeed feasible to incorporate annotations into the classes generated from an Avro schema. Avro facilitates the inclusion of custom annotations within the schema's field and class definitions. These annotations serve the purpose of offering supplementary details about the fields or classes, and they also enable the customization of code generation.

To add custom annotations to the generated Avro classes at the class level, you can use the `@AvroCustom` annotation provided by the plugin. The @AvroCustom annotation allows you to specify custom annotations to be added to generated classes, fields, or methods.

Open your `build.gradle` file. Inside the avro configuration block, add a new @AvroCustom annotation to specify custom annotations for the class level. For example:

```
avro {
    source("src/main/avro") {
        outputDir = file("build/generated-sources/avro")
        stringType = "String"
        createSetters = true
        fieldVisibility = "PRIVATE"
        // Add the @AvroCustom annotation for the class level
        classLevelAnnotations = ["@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)"]
    }
}
```

In the above configuration, we've added the @AvroCustom annotation with the **classLevelAnnotations attribute** to specify the custom annotation for the class level. In this case, we're adding `@DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class)` to the generated Avro classes.

After making this configuration change, the @DefaultSchema(JavaBeanSchema.class) annotation will be added to the class level of the generated Avro classes when you run the Gradle task for Avro code generation. Make sure to adjust the annotation and values as needed for your specific use case.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, classLevelAnnotations - is it real property in DefaultAvroExtension class for this plugin? which plugin's version contains it?

Comment: https://github.com/davidmc24/gradle-avro-plugin/ - here in options it's not mentioned((